# Is it possible to run multiple dpus(xmodels) using PYNQ in kriakv260 board?

Tags: fpga, vitis-ai

Im trying to run multiple xmodels in pynq by loading separate dpus.

I tried the dpu overlay by importing dpu.bit
but im not sure if its loading the same dpu or different dpus.is there any other way using pynq to run multiple dpus?